# Creating a unique position counter for nodes with the same name but different children elements

Tags: xml, excel, xslt

I am trying to do an XSLT transformation.

The XML input looks like this

```
<root>
    <row>
        <col1>John</col1>
        <col2>2</col2>
        <col3>Hello<col3>
   <row>
        <col1>John</col1>
        <col2>3</col2>
        <col3>Hello<col3>
   <row>
        <col1>Eddie</col1>
        <col2>3</col2>
        <col3>Hello<col3>
```

I am transforming XML data and opening it in Excel. I'm trying to create some sort of position counter in Excel. Each row indicates a person's file. Some files span multiple rows as shown above. What I want to create is a row position counter for each file. For example, John would have two rows of data in the excel sheet. I want one line to have the counter read "1" and the other line read "2". While, Eddie's position counter would only read "1".

What should I be looking at or trying to do?

Comment: Before even starting to write the XSLT for this, you need to know what you are transforming your XML too, so if you could edit your question to show your expected output, that would help a lot. As for the transformation itself, this looks very much like a grouping problem. Assuming you are using XSLT 1.0, take a look at http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html which explains how to do "Muenchian Grouping" in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Your XML does not look valid, as it has now closing row tags. Can you create a valid sample as well as an output sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is already sorted, you might get away without grouping it. For example, given a **well-formed test input**:

```
<root>
    <row>
        <col1>Alpha</col1>
        <col2>001</col2>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col1>Alpha</col1>
        <col2>002</col2>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col1>Alpha</col1>
        <col2>003</col2>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col1>Bravo</col1>
        <col2>004</col2>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col1>Bravo</col1>
        <col2>005</col2>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col1>Charlie</col1>
        <col2>006</col2>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col1>Delta</col1>
        <col2>007</col2>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col1>Delta</col1>
        <col2>008</col2>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col1>Delta</col1>
        <col2>009</col2>
    </row>
</root>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="row">
            <xsl:copy>
                <col0>
                    <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::row[col1=current()/col1])+1"/>
                </col0>
                <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <row>
      <col0>1</col0>
      <col1>Alpha</col1>
      <col2>001</col2>
   </row>
   <row>
      <col0>2</col0>
      <col1>Alpha</col1>
      <col2>002</col2>
   </row>
   <row>
      <col0>3</col0>
      <col1>Alpha</col1>
      <col2>003</col2>
   </row>
   <row>
      <col0>1</col0>
      <col1>Bravo</col1>
      <col2>004</col2>
   </row>
   <row>
      <col0>2</col0>
      <col1>Bravo</col1>
      <col2>005</col2>
   </row>
   <row>
      <col0>1</col0>
      <col1>Charlie</col1>
      <col2>006</col2>
   </row>
   <row>
      <col0>1</col0>
      <col1>Delta</col1>
      <col2>007</col2>
   </row>
   <row>
      <col0>2</col0>
      <col1>Delta</col1>
      <col2>008</col2>
   </row>
   <row>
      <col0>3</col0>
      <col1>Delta</col1>
      <col2>009</col2>
   </row>
</output>
```

**Note**: this is not a very fast method; if you have a very large data set, you may have to wait a bit.