# Creating a counter that returns an incremental value for unique child elements XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am attempting to do an XSLT Transformation. I want to create a counter that returns the an incremental value for each unique "col1". So for example for all rows that have col1 "Alpha", I want a value of 1. All rows that have col1 "Bravo" I want a value of 2. And for col1 "Charlie" all rows have a value of 3, and other unique col1's would keep incrementing and so on. Do I need to create a variable or some kind of thing that compares one string to another string and increments it? I'm not really sure how to approach this...

```
 <root>
  <row>
    <col1>Alpha</col1>
    <col2>123</col2>
    <col3>ABC</col3>
  </row>
  <row>
    <col1>Alpha</col1>
    <col2>234</col2>
    <col3>BCD</col3>
  </row>
   <row>
    <col1>Bravo</col1>
    <col2>123</col2>
    <col3>ABC</col3>
  <row>
    <col1>Bravo</col1>
    <col2>234</col2>
    <col3>BCD</col3>
  </row>
  <row>
    <col1>Bravo</col1>
    <col2>345</col2>
    <col3>CDE</col3>
  </row>
  <row>
    <col1>Charlie</col1>
    <col2>123</col2>
    <col3>ABC</col3>
  </row>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If - as in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005159/creating-a-unique-position-counter-for-nodes-with-the-same-name-but-different-ch) - your data is already sorted, you can use a very similar:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="row">
            <xsl:copy>
                <col0>
                    <xsl:value-of select="count((. | preceding-sibling::row)[col1!=preceding-sibling::row[1]/col1])+1"/>
                </col0>
                <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This increases the count on each "break" in `col1`, not necessarily by unique values.

Comment: This worked perfectly! I tried modifying the code you gave me from my previous, but kept messing it up and had lots of errors resulting. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you can use XSLT 2.0, you can use a combination of `distinct-values()` and `index-of()`.

If your data is not sorted, it will give the index of the first occurrence.

**XML Input**

```
<root>
    <row>
        <col1>Alpha</col1>
        <col2>123</col2>
        <col3>ABC</col3>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col1>Alpha</col1>
        <col2>234</col2>
        <col3>BCD</col3>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col1>Bravo</col1>
        <col2>123</col2>
        <col3>ABC</col3>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col1>Bravo</col1>
        <col2>234</col2>
        <col3>BCD</col3>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col1>Bravo</col1>
        <col2>345</col2>
        <col3>CDE</col3>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col1>Charlie</col1>
        <col2>123</col2>
        <col3>ABC</col3>
    </row>
</root>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:variable name="col1s" select="distinct-values(/*/row/col1)"/>

    <xsl:template match="col1">
        <col0><xsl:value-of select="index-of($col1s,.)"/></col0>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<root>
   <row>
      <col0>1</col0>
      <col1>Alpha</col1>
      <col2>123</col2>
      <col3>ABC</col3>
   </row>
   <row>
      <col0>1</col0>
      <col1>Alpha</col1>
      <col2>234</col2>
      <col3>BCD</col3>
   </row>
   <row>
      <col0>2</col0>
      <col1>Bravo</col1>
      <col2>123</col2>
      <col3>ABC</col3>
   </row>
   <row>
      <col0>2</col0>
      <col1>Bravo</col1>
      <col2>234</col2>
      <col3>BCD</col3>
   </row>
   <row>
      <col0>2</col0>
      <col1>Bravo</col1>
      <col2>345</col2>
      <col3>CDE</col3>
   </row>
   <row>
      <col0>3</col0>
      <col1>Charlie</col1>
      <col2>123</col2>
      <col3>ABC</col3>
   </row>
</root>
```